# MD + LUKS + LVM will not cleanly shutdown

Tags: encryption, lvm, mdadm, luks

My setup is currently raid1 + luks on each md partition and lvm on top to stripe between the arrays. There is only one volume group with one logical volume currently.

```
sdc                             8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdc1                          8:33   0   1.8T  0 part
  └─md127                       9:127  0   1.8T  0 raid1
    └─data-crypt0 (dm-3)      252:3    0   1.8T  0 crypt
      └─data_raid-data (dm-5) 252:5    0   2.7T  0 lvm   /mnt/data
sdd                             8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdd1                          8:49   0 931.5G  0 part
  └─md126                       9:126  0 931.4G  0 raid1
    └─data-crypt1 (dm-4)      252:4    0 931.4G  0 crypt
      └─data_raid-data (dm-5) 252:5    0   2.7T  0 lvm   /mnt/data
```

I'm able to startup the device via

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md/data:0 data-crypt0     # decrypt
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md/data:1 data-crypt1     # decrypt
vgchange -ay /dev/data_raid                        # turn on lvm
mount /dev/data_raid/data /mnt/data                # mount
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to go the opposite direction and turn the thing off.

```
umount /mnt/data            # ok
vgchange -an /dev/data_raid # ok
cryptsetup luksClose data-crypt0 # fail
```

For some reason I see the following, several times, and the device does not shut down.

```
device-mapper: remove ioctl on data-crypt0 failed: Device or resource busy
```

This is after a reboot and all I have done is the commands I've shown without ever using any of the data on the partition. I'd like some suggestions if anyone has something on either the setup or how to get it to shutdown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue while installing Ubuntu 13.04. For some reason (possibly a bug), `vgchange -a n` does not remove the device mappings. As a result, the LVM physical volume (i.e. the LUKS container) is still considered in use, and can not be luksClose'd.

Check if you have the same issue using `dmsetup ls`. If it lists any of your data_raid Logical Volumes, and they persist even after `vgchange -a n`, you may remove them using `dmsetup remove NAME`.

Once all device mappings have been removed, you should be able to luksClose.

Comment: This works, despite being super annoying. =/ But thanks!

Comment: In a similar setup on 14.04, `vgchange -a n` cleanly closes everything, and `cryptsetup luksClose` works.